# Wordpress/php and base64 encoded images - jpeg works

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

I'm facing some problems, where i do not even have an idea how to get rid of those.
We moved our wordpress blog to a new server (Centos6, newest version of php, mysql).

We now noticed that a colleague just pasted many pictures into the wordpress editor, so that simply the base64 code is inserted into the article. This worked on the old server, but not on the new one.

If its an jpeg, it works like it used to. But if it's an png, all attributes are quotet with primes (”) and even the following normal elements are not working anymore.

This is how an element looks in the debugger:

```
<img class="”aligncenter”" alt="”"" src="”data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAl...”">
```

I checked my first ideas like mime types, but nothing helped. Then I updated php on the old server - There it still works. 
The encoding of the files seem to be us-ascii (same on the old server).

The funny thing is - it works in the backend, but not in the frontend.

I have no idea. Any hints appreciated,

Best,
Kddc